# Runtime Directory in Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, intellij-idea

I have a android project with a runtime directory, and there is a jar file in this directory. This project can be built in eclipse. However, if I put the jar file in some other place, say, libs directory. This project would fail to build. In addition, even if I place the jar file in the runtime directory, this project cannot be built in Intellij. When the project fails to build, the error logs looks like the following.

> Android Dex: [GameDemo] EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
>
> ..... bad range 5..6; actual size 5
>
> at bytecode offset 0000005
>
> while processing  ()V

So here are my questions:

1. Given a project in Eclipse, why project can be built when the jar file is in runtime library, but not when it's in libs directory.
2. Even though the jar is in runtime directory, why this project cannot be built in Itellij. What's the difference in build process of the two ide in term of android project.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `runtime directory`?

Comment: A directory name runtime

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having this issue because you are trying to integrate CMCC's mobile SDK. It's a piece of garbage but that's another topic. For your purpose, just setting the library as "Provided" instead of "Compile" in the module settings of your IntelliJ project will get you past the compile stage. the SDK's probably loading it on the fly but not sure why that's necessary. Also be careful how you add the dynamic lib they provided. Make sure you do a plain copy instead of through the android NDK module dependency crap.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, and your guess is correct. Indeed I was dealing with CMCC mobile SDK. I figured this out a few days ago, but my case is not only get this piece of sh*t working in Intellij. The jar file they provided is only used in compiling but not dexing. They leveraged the so file to weave all the classes, types at runtime. Anyway, thank you for providing me this information.

Comment: Still get the error, set to "provided" don't work for me. I'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Seems they wanna avoid their sdk to be easily decompiled and byte hacked.

So they provided a dev time lib written in java that has interface feature only and implemented the real logic/type/class in a native lib.

Comment: Indeed, they made it. However, their mechanism may fail once ART becomes the default runtime environment.